# Can I create an object in a constructor when I create a class in C#

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public class ContentViewModel
{
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public bool UseRowKey { 
        get {
            return Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
               Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";
        }
    }
    public string TempRowKey { get; set; }

}
```

I'm doing this now:

```
        var vm = new ContentViewModel();
        vm.Content = new Content(pk);
        vm.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
        vm.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
```

Is there some way that I could change my ContentViewModel so that I don't need to do the last three 
statements?

Comment: Of course... Just put those three statements in your constructor, using `this.Content` instead of `vm.Content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass in a parameter to your constructor?

```
public class ContentViewModel
{
    public ContentViewModel(SomeType pk)
    {
        Content = new Content(pk); //use pk in the Content constructor to set other params
    }  
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public bool UseRowKey { 
        get {
            return Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
               Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";
        }
    }
    public string TempRowKey { get; set; }
}
```

In general consider OOP and the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter): Don't access nested properties if you don't have to and tell objects *what* to do but not *how* (let the object itself decide on that).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that I could extend this a bit and make it so I could alternatively create the ContentViewModel and have another constructor where I pass in a Content object?

Comment: Yes - just add another constructor that accepts a `Content` instance as you said. You can overload constructors just as you can with methods.

Comment: Do I have to use the word "this" in the constructor?

Comment: @Gemma: No - it's only used as a convention to indicate that you are using an instance variable as opposed to a local variable - this is only needed if both local and instance variable have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah like this:

```
public class ContentViewModel 
{ 
    public ContentViewModel(Content c) 
    {
        if (c == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot create Content VM with null content.");
        this.Content = c;
    }
    public ContentViewModel(object pk) : this(Guid.NewGuid()) {}
    public ContentViewModel(object pk)
    {
        this.Content = new Content(pk); 
        this.Content.PartitionKey = pk; 
        this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now; 
    }

    public Content Content { get; set; } 
    public bool UseRowKey {  
        get { 
            return Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" || 
               Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06"; 
        } 
    } 
    public string TempRowKey { get; set; } 

}
```

Comment: GlennFerrieLive - Can you explain what the 2nd line does. Sorry but I don't understand it? Also is there aa way that I could create ContentViewModel and pass in a content object as a constructor?

Comment: Yes.  The second like is an "empty" constructor and it calls another of the classes constructors with some default arguments.  I will add a third constructor to my sample that takes 'Content'

Answer (score 1):

may `object initializer` be useful:

```
var vm = new ContentViewModel {Content = new Content {PartitionKey = pk, Created = DateTime.Now}};
```

all in one line.